# Can Getopt::Long GetOptions generate an error if the same option occurs multiple times?

Tags: perl, getopt-long

I have this getopt:

```
GetOptions(  GetOptions ("library=s" => \@libfiles);
    @libfiles = split(/,/,join(',',@libfiles));
     "help" => \$help,
     "input=s" => \$fileordir,
     "pretty-xml:4" => \$pretty
);
```

Is it possible for `Getopt::Long::GetOptions` to detect if the same option is provided on the command line multiple times?  For example, I would like the following to generate an error:

```
perl script.pl --input=something --input=something
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there is direct way but you have two options:

- Use an array and check after processing the options

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/perl

  use warnings;
  use strict;

  use Getopt::Long;

  my @options;
  my $result = GetOptions ('option=i' => \@options);

  if ( @options > 1 ) {
     die 'Error: --option can be specified only once';
  }
  ```
- Use a subroutine and check if the option is already defined

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/perl

  use warnings;
  use strict;

  use Getopt::Long;

  my $option;
  my $result = GetOptions (
      'option=i' => sub {
          if ( defined $option) {
              die 'Error: --option can be specified only once';
          } else {
              $option = $_[1]; 
          }
      }
  );
  ```

  In this case you can use an exclamation mark `!` at the beginning of the `die` and the error will be catched and reported as a usual Getopt error (see the [documentation of Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#User-defined-subroutines-to-handle-options) for the details)